# QGIS/PDAL: Selecting/tagging equally-spaced subset of point data

Tags: qgis, point-cloud, pdal

I have a set of high-density bathymetric point data with a maximum density of 30m. I now want to select or otherwise differentiate a subset of these points, evenly distributed throughout the set at an average spacing of 100m or so. (This is for visualization purposes.) There is no meaningful difference between the points to be selected and the others, so the selection is essentially random but must be fairly regular in its spacing.

It is easy, of course, to downsample it with PDAL, but the issue is that I need to preserve both the high-density and low-density points in the same database, without duplication. I need a way to mark a subset of these points without creating redundant data.

I've tried the following:

- Resampling to a lower density with PDAL. This could be a good solution but I haven't been able to find a way to preserve the discarded points as a separate set, or how to compare the original point set to the modified one.
- Random selection via QGIS. Not even enough. The selected points tend to occur in clusters with large gaps between them.